# Автоматически подставить значение из инпута

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть два инпута, первый `name` и второй `keywords`. У инпута `keywords` по умолчанию стоит значение и некий плейсхолдер у значения. Выглядит это так:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="Купить {name}, цены на {name} />
```

Вопрос собственно в том, можно ли как нибудь автоматически брать значение из поля `name` и подставлять в `{name}` поля `keywords`?
Думаю может как то в value засунуть переменную, в которой будит значение с поля `name`, но даже не представляю как.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить обработчик события на поле name.
В примере при изменении значения в поле name, будет обновляться значение поля keywords.

```js
var ctKeywords = $('input[name="keywords"]');

$('input[name="name"]').keyup(function(e) {
  var name = $(this).val() || '(наименование не указано)';
  $(ctKeywords).val('Купить ' + name + ', цены на ' + name);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="keywords" value="Купить (наименование не указано), цены на (наименование не указано)" />
```